# Fragment内でサービスを起動する

Tags: android, fragment

現在`Fragment`の中から`startActivity`でサービスを起動させようとしているのですが、「`Unable to find explicit activity class have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`」とエラーが出てしまいます。`Manifest.xml`を確認したのですが、`<service android:name="ServiceContact"/>`というように、サービスタグを設定しています。
`Fragment`の中からサービスは起動することはできないのでしょうか？
以下のようにしてサービスを起動させています。

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ServiceContact.class));
```

どなたか分かる方がいればご教授いただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

サービスの起動には、`startActivity()`メソッドではなく、`startService()`メソッドを使います。

`Fragment`には`startService()`がないので、`getActivity()`で取得した`Activity Context`を利用します。

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ServiceContact.class);
getActivity().startService(intent);
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。startServiceに変更することで動きました！ありがとうございました。